# Brown spots on echeveria

Tags: succulents

I have had this echeveria for 3 years now. It has grown a lot. It is kept outside in a very sunny spot. We are in Redwood City, CA. It has suddenly developed these brown spots. It was repotted last year and it has overgrown its current pot, but I don't think the spots are because of that. Would this because of the cold?[image] It has been cold at night (50F) here these days. Is this scales, what is the best way to treat this. [image]

Comment: Did you have a hail storm recently? As a sign, you may have the marks mostly on the upper parts of the leaves.

Comment: A local master gardener program also suggested a hail storm. We did have on recently I think.

Answer (score 1):

Though im no expert on succulents but those brown spots look a lot like bite marks. Have you scanned the plant and the surrounding area for any visible pests? Also, 50F isn't what's normally considered too cold to bring your plants inside.

Comment: Yes, haven't seen any insects on it.

Comment: Well it's either sunburn or something has been nibbling at it. It's best to search for the culprit at night when it's dark. For now, move the plant away from the rest of your plants while it's current condition is being examined. As far as heat stress is concerned, I've heard that succulents produce a white powder like coating that acts like a sunscreen to protect the plant from overheating. Now i don't know if that powder is something that can be scraped off. You'll have to check it and adress that on your own.